# How much does the ionosphere contribute to the earth's magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If it is random I would assume it is negligible. But can it ever have a net direction and polarity due to a strong solar wind, storm or by artificial resonance means that would then have a net impact on the earth's magnetic field? And could we influence it with strong radio and microwaves to impact the magnetic field of the earth to help stabilize the field if needed? Specifically to keep a pole shift from occurring. And is there real physics behind a potential pole shift?

Comment: Look for information on the magnetosphere.

Comment: Earth Sciences SE might be better. Yes, there is real physics behind pole flips.

Comment: It takes a few thousand years for poles to flip. So whatever issues may arise, trying to "stabilize" the field is probably a useless endeavor.